# Need TIGER/line national (USA) road files, not per county

Tags: r, data, census, tiger

I'm trying to get the TIGER/line files for roads to create a raster of major and minor road density for about half of the USA.

The problem is the interactive tool provided
(https://www.census.gov/cgi-bin/geo/shapefiles/index.php?year=2020&layergroup=Roads)
is very limited in use, in that you can only download the primary roads nationwise.
I also need secondary roads, and preferably even unpaved roads, but it seems like those can only be downloaded per county?

I thought the tigris package in r would help, but it seems like while there is a way to request multiple counties at once
(see https://rpubs.com/walkerke/tigris01)
I would still need to type every county to get all roads for a state, and do this for the +/- 30 states I need the data for?

I'm hoping someone knows how I can get my hands on primary, secondary, and preferably all roads of the contiguous United States, or a simpler way to get it per state?

Comment: If it’s open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They have less advertised Esri geodatabase files that contain the full country:

https://www.census.gov/geographies/mapping-files/time-series/geo/tiger-geodatabase-file.html

Answer (score 0):

http://download.geofabrik.de/ It's OSM data but much more comprehensive. I know this is late but I thought I would answer for all the people researching the same topic.